# iPhone Medical app that retains information through an upgrade

Tags: iphone

Is there a medical application for the iphone where you do not lose all info entered when getting an upgraded iphone?  I did not realize I would lose all the information I entered.

Comment: Please add more detail.  What do you mean by "getting an upgraded phone"?  And what does the medical application need to achieve?

Comment: If you buy a newer model iPhone or upgrade to a newer operating system, you shouldn't lose this data.  Something's gone wrong during the upgrade.  If you restore from a backup from before the upgrade, you should get your data back.

Answer (score 1):

Most iOS apps will transfer data to a new iOS device if the old device with the app data is Sync'd and backed-up to iTunes on a Mac or PC, and the new device is then restored from the backup of that old device on the same Mac or PC.

You might want to make a backup of your iTunes backups to be more safe.

If you don't want to restore from backup, but set up a device as new (blank), the you may need to find a medical web app where your info is stored online somewhere.

In the future, there may be some iCloud enabled apps (assuming they can somehow meet HIPPA requirements with your private medical info).

Answer (score 0):

This answers your question, but the question is extremly unclear:
https://www.quentiq.com/content/